# windows phone8 browser, Ajax call not working (ajax-json-dust-cordova(phonegap))

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm using cordova and dust.js (HTML templating) in my app. I make Ajax requests that return json objects.

**Platforms the App is working on:**
--Android browser,FF, chrome and Apk
--iPhone
--PC firefox and IE11 (1 out of 3 pc's wasn't able to make the ajax calls too)
--Windows phone 8 app

**Problem:**
When I try the windows phone 8 internet explorer, no ajax calls succeed in my app.

**Details and solutions I tried**
1- The json response is returned correctly as I checked the server log that the ajax call is made to... 
2- This problem happens in GET requests as well as POST requests...
3- The ajax is not excuting neither the done nor the fail:

```
$.ajax({
        type: httpMethod,
        url: host + url,
        data: data,
        async: asyncFlag,
        dataType: "json",
        error: errFn,
        dataFilter: dataFilter,
        success: (successFn),
        timeout: 60000
    }).done(function(msg) {
       alert( "done" );     
    }).fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
    });
```

4- I tried adding cache:false in the above request, didn't solve the problem.